# Dart-flutter (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

Tags: json, flutter, dart, import, pubspec

i am building a app just to test my skills but im facing an error importing a json file in my project
here is my translation code for translating ayah in my app. File is located at assets/repository/translation.json. also in the init state of my main file i used loadtranslations.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:islam_plus/models/translation_model.dart';
import 'package:quran/quran.dart' as quran;

class TranslationService {
  final String _filePath = 'assets/repository/translation.json';



  List<AyahTranslation> translationList = [];

  Future<void> loadTranslations() async {
    final jsonString = await File(_filePath).readAsString();
    print(jsonString);
    final jsonBody = jsonDecode(jsonString);
    print(jsonBody);
    final List<dynamic> quranList = jsonBody['quran'];

    translationList = quranList
        .map((dynamic item) => AyahTranslation.fromJson(item))
        .toList();
  }

  List<AyahTranslation> getAyahTranslation(int surahNumber) {
    final totalVerseCount = quran.getVerseCount(surahNumber);
    int verseCount = 1;

    final translationFiltered = translationList.where((translation) {
      if (surahNumber == translation.chapter) {
        verseCount++;

        if (verseCount > totalVerseCount) {
          verseCount = 1;
        }
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }).toList();
    return translationFiltered;
  }

  String getRandomTranslation(int surahNumber, int verseNumber) {
    final translationList = getAyahTranslation(surahNumber);
    final translation = translationList.firstWhere(
        (translation) => translation.verse == verseNumber,
        orElse: () => AyahTranslation(
            chapter: surahNumber,
            verse: verseNumber,
            text: 'Translation Not found'));

    return translation.text;
  }
}
```

here is the pubspec yaml

```
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/number_star.png
    - assets/repository/translation.json

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware
```

here is the main file init state

```
class _QuranPageState extends State<QuranPage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  final service = QuranService();
  late TabController _tabController;
  TranslationService _translationService = TranslationService();

  onTabChange(int index) {}

  @override
  void initState() {
    _translationService.loadTranslations();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 4, vsync: this);
    super.initState();
  }
```

here is the error i am getting

```
E/flutter (10333): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PathNotFoundException: Cannot open file, path = 'assets/repository/translation.json' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

the app runs fine but when i click an surah to see the translation i get the range error i suppose the error is because of the empty list which is dependent on the translation file.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass the path to a `File` object if you want to load the json from your assets.

Try this:

```
final String data = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("assets/repository/translation.json");
final json = jsonDecode(data);
```

You could also use `rootBundle`:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart'

final String data = rootBundle.loadString("assets/repository/translation.json");
final json = jsonDecode(data);
```